# Python: How to see if a unix timestamp is before or after a time of day

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

I'm trying to figure out if a unix timestamp is after 21:00. However, I'm having type errors.

This is my code:

```
from datetime import datetime, time
theTime=1497204737
the_date = (
        datetime.fromtimestamp(
            int(theTime)
        ).strftime('%H:%M:%S')
)
if the_date >= time(21,00):
    print("we did it!")
```

I keep getting this error:

```
TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'datetime.time'
```

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you convert the timestamp to a `datetime` but then you convert it to a string again:

```
>>> the_date = datetime.fromtimestamp(int(theTime)).strftime('%H:%M:%S')
>>> type(the_date)
str
```

There are several ways to make it work:

For example you could simply keep the timestamp as `datetime` and compare the `hours`:

```
from datetime import datetime, time
theTime=1497204737

the_date = datetime.fromtimestamp(int(theTime))

if the_date.hour >= 21:
    print("we did it!")
```

or convert the `datetime` to a `time` and compare the `time`s:

```
if time(the_date.hour, the_date.minute) >= time(21, 0):
    print("we did it!")
```